# See previous and subsequent versions of a JSFiddle page

Tags: jsfiddle

Is there any way to see all previous and subsequent versions of a JSFiddle page?

[This page here](http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/510/) was edited from a previous version, but I can't find a list of previous versions.

I hope JSFiddle has some kind of revision history tool that makes it possible to see previous and later versions of a page.

Does such a feature exist?

Answer (score 6):

There may be a better way, but the last number of the URL is the revision number:

> http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/**510**/

To look at other versions you can just change that, although with 535 versions it could be fun finding the one you want!

Comment: It appears that revision 1 doesn't exist. Why is this? http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/1/

Comment: @AndersonGreen possibly the base version http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/ is 1 so only `/2/` upwards are available?

Comment: Also, do these revisions go in exact sequential order (so that the previous number corresponds to the previous version), or does the revision get changed to the number after the last revision whenever any revision is edited?

Comment: When I saved changes to this version: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/14/ the revision number was changed to 537, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/537/ It appears that the ordering of the revision numbers does not give any clear indication of the exact revision history. Is there a better way to check the revision history (and see each "branch" of the revisions?)

Comment: @AndersonGreen you're correct it does just increment. It doesn't appear the versioning is particularly robust, I think it is worth remembering that JSFiddle is a site for trying out things rather than extended development.

Comment: At first I was guessing that they might not use base 10 numbers for their revision history. But I can't figure out what else explains the fact that you now seem to be on number 545, with revision numbers 1 through 544 prior. Of course, I didn't check to see if the content were unique. I am inclined to agree with @JohnC at this point. Given the purpose (and cost) of using JSFiddle, it probably isn't as robust as Mercurial etc.