# Finding the older version of a JSFiddle by entering new version like 200

Tags: jsfiddle

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/201/) and its latest version is 201. I had made some problems in the 200 version and without rectifying the problem I pressed the update button, so the the new version is now 201. Now, when I wanted to get the 200 version, it’s showing

> Error 404
>   We're truly sorry, but there is no such page

If the 201 version is there, then the 200 version is obviously present. How do I get to the 200 version?

**Note:** I have gone through this [See previous and subsequent versions of a jsfiddle page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36809/see-previous-and-subsequent-versions-of-a-jsfiddle-page) but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your `url` and at the end where they have written `201` remove `201` and type `200` and hit enter it will take you to your previous version.

Comment: This is already suggested in [the linked answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36810/21583).